# payment intent is null in a subscription checkout session

Tags: stripe-payments

I am integrating stripe using php by following this tutorial:
https://phppot.com/php/manage-recurring-payments-using-stripe-billing-in-php/
(my website has some subscription plans and redirects to the stripe checkout form ) . however, for the last step, I decided not to use webhooks, I chose to store the info like in this tutorial https://www.codexworld.com/stripe-checkout-payment-gateway-integration-php/ (I know it is not for subscription but I just use the success.php code from this tutorial to collect the customer info and payment intent details).
I tested it, gone throught the stripe checkout form , and on success I printed the checkout session object and noticed that the payment_intent field of that object is empty ! so i cannot load the payment intent object and get its info although the payment is successfully made and it is showing on the dashboard . any idea why ??

EDIT :
According to the documenttaion of a checkout session (https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object), the payment_intent  field stores the ID of the PaymentIntent for Checkout Sessions in payment mode. In my case I have a subscription mode not a payment one. however,if I still want to  get the $intent->status , can I use the payment_status field of the session object  $checkout_session->payment_status?
And if subcription payments really don't have paymentintents , then why did the payment appear in the payments section on the dashboard?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on the `mode` you passed in, either one of `payment_intent`, `subscription` or `setup_intent` will be populated, the rest will be `null`.

When a `Subscription` is made, your user is invoiced so it is considered a payment and will appear in the Payments dashboard. You can retrieve the `Subscription` and access the `latest_invoice` field to obtain the `Invoice` object. The `Invoice` object contains the `payment_intent` field. This is likely what you're looking for.

Using webhook would simplify the process, since you could listen to `invoice.payment_suceeded` to retrieve the PaymentIntent ID.

Comment: Thank you so much ! I would like to use webhooks but should i simply put invoice.payment_succeeded instead of the list mentioned here ? https://phppot.com/php/manage-recurring-payments-using-stripe-billing-in-php/  .. I avoided using webhooks, because all the sending processes fail  (probably beacuse of the test mode) so i couldn't test my code and the second problem is that subscription_updated event is appearing instead of subscription_created.

Comment: You do not have to listen to all the webhook events. It really depends on your business flow. But yes, the list mentioned is the full list of Subscription life cycle events that Stripe will send to your webhook URL. 

Test mode doesn't have an effect on webhook. You need to have an server endpoint that the Stripe server can reach. Alternatively, you can redirect webhook to your localhost web server https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/test

Comment: `subscription_updated` because there's likely already an existing `Subscription`, and details of it has changed, e.g. new start/end period, invoice, etc. `subscription_created` only ever happens once for every new `Subscription`.

Comment: Thnk you for your answers, no in fact it is a new user subscribing for the first time and passing through the stripe payment form , so it is not updated ,it must be created ..

Comment: for the webhooks i still get sending failed next to each sent webhook in the dashboard.

Comment: "Do note that these are fake events with fake IDs (e.g., evt_1234). They cannot be fetched through the API and do not contain real, actionable data." This is written in the link that you have sent.I think that for this reason,  the queries mentioned in the tutorial that I followed  have not been executed  on test mode and for this reason they  have a 'failed' status. If these hooks will become successful on live mode, that would be great. But I still need a way to test my queries in test mode.

Comment: If you send a test webhook event, then yes, you're right. Instead, try forwarding the webhook event to localhost, and fire an actual event by going through the Checkout flow like a normal user. Make sure you're listening to `checkout.session.completed` event. As for the new/updated subscription, I'm not exactly sure what happened. I recommend doing a live chat with Stripe so they can check more in-depth for you.

Comment: Currently I am going through the whole process like a normal user but I am specifying my test website as an endpoint and i am using a test account in stripe dashboard (test public and private keys). So for now I should specify my localhost like the link you have sent instead instead of my test site?

Comment: Again it is not wrong to perform my queries on the success page  (specified by the success _url) using the invoice object and getting the intent status like you described in your comment in case webhooks didn't function on my site? right?

Comment: Yes, it is not wrong. But do read this to consider the implication. : https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse#retrieve-checkout-session. I'll paste an abstract in the next comment.

Comment: "The right choice depends on your tolerance for dropoff, as customers may not always reach the success_url after a successful payment. It’s possible for them close their browser tab before the redirect occurs. Handling webhooks prevents your integration from being susceptible to this form of dropoff."

Comment: No problem. If my answer has helped, please give me a vote~ :P

Comment: I did  but i have less than 15 reputations so it doesn't show up. :)

Comment: I retreive the invocie and payment intent was set to null, what should i do ? Maybe some additional params to include ?

Comment: That's likely because no payment was initiated against that Invoice yet. Your invoice is still likely in the `draft` state. Check out the lifecycle of it here https://stripe.com/docs/invoicing/overview